# Javascript closure in for loop - does the variable used count?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm new to javascript closures. My question is, in the SO post about [javacript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), the first code block

```js
var funcs = [];
// let's create 3 functions
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // and store them in funcs
  funcs[i] = function() {
    // each should log its value.
    console.log("My value: " + i);
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  // and now let's run each one to see
  funcs[j]();
}
```

outputs

> My value: 3
>
> My value: 3
>
> My value: 3

But how is it that when I re-use `i` variable in the second for loop, there is no closure?

```js
var funcs = [];
// let's create 3 functions
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // and store them in funcs
  funcs[i] = function() {
    // each should log its value.
    console.log("My value: " + i);
  };
}
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // and now let's run each one to see
  funcs[i]();
}
```

How is the output in the second code block

> My value: 0
>
> My value: 1
>
> My value: 2

Comment: The answer seems pretty clear--you're logging `i`, and in the first case it's always 3 while in the second case it's reset to 0 and counts up to 3. In both cases, it's probably an unintended result. If you use `let` instead of `var` there's no confusion.

Comment: @ggorlen, I read the answer, and it doesn't quite answer my question: how is `i` captured in the first block different from the `i` captured in the second block?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean--it's not different. That's the whole problem with `var`, it creates variables that aren't scoped to the block.

Comment: In both examples, you're using the same `i` variable declared at the first loop. But in the second example, you reset the `i` variable to `0`, so what is its value on the first iteration of the second loop? It's `0`. You then increment it to `1`. So what's its value a the second iteration of the second loop? It's `1`.. and so on.

Comment: ...you may be less confused if you move the `var` declaration of `i` to the very top of the code. That's actually where it takes place, irrespective of where you put `var`, and of how many times you re-declare it.

Answer (score 0):

Use let keyword for variables declared inside for loops(let i, let j). Its working